# Changing the Selected Item's Background Color in a Windows 8 Store App's ItemView

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro

I'm working with an ItemView in my recent Windows 8 app, however, the selected item has this icky blue/purple background that I would prefer to replace with something that fits the app more.

Unfortunately, as this is a Windows 8 app, the documentation is very limited beyond Microsoft's own and my searches have not turned up anything of use.

I'm wondering if anyone has figured out how to do this in "The Interface Previously Called Metro" Apps.

I have written my app in C#.

EDIT: Solution

You may add resources to your App.xaml ResourceDictionary. If they match the name of the resource used by a control they will override that value. This works for all controls, not just ItemView's. The overridden resources will also appear in Blend.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To override the default purple accents on selected item, you need to override some of the brushes in a resource dictionary and provide your own colours:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <!-- overrides -->
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListViewItemSelectedPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush" Color="#00FFFFFF" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListViewItemSelectedPointerOverBorderThemeBrush" Color="#80FFFFFF" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListViewItemSelectedBackgroundThemeBrush" Color="#40FFFFFF" />

</ResourceDictionary>
```

Comment: Thanks, that is much easier than the other's that Google and Bing were suggesting which involved a significant amount of code.

Comment: Yep, had to experiment a bit with overriding the entire template, before I found I could do this :)

Answer (score 0):

I found this even better:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListViewItemSelectedPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush" Color="Transparent" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListViewItemSelectedPointerOverBorderThemeBrush" Color="Transparent"  />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListViewItemSelectedBackgroundThemeBrush" Color="Transparent" />
```